# Could not resolve phonepe.intentsdk.android.release

Tags: react-native, payumoney

I am using version 2.1.0 of payu-non-seam-less-react,
after installation, it shows me the 403 from the server. I am not able to run the app ...

Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

> Could not download IntentSDK-0.1.5.4.aar (phonepe.intentsdk.android.release:IntentSDK:0.1.5.4)
> > Could not get resource 'https://phonepe.bintray.com/PhonePeIntentSDK/phonepe/intentsdk/android/release/IntentSDK/0.1.5.4/IntentSDK-0.1.5.4.aar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://phonepe.bintray.com/PhonePeIntentSDK/phonepe/intentsdk/android/release/IntentSDK/0.1.5.4/IntentSDK-0.1.5.4.aar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.